How to control color bar secondary y axis ticks
I've got a colorbar displaying the log of probability for some data.  I want a 2nd set of ticks for the colorbar that displays "raw" probability values.  I have this working somewhat, but I am struggling to control the tick locations and number of ticks for the 2nd set of ticks.  My code is below.  If I increase the number of ticks I'm asking for, I just get a tighter bunch of ticks near the top of the bar, which makes it unreadable and is not what I want anyway.  I'd like a few more lower down, representing probabilities below 0.1.  In the images, the difference is due to cbar_nbins_2 = 10 and cbar_nbins_2 = 15, which does have an affect, though it's clear that I'm not getting "exactly" what I'm asking for (for instance, I don't get exactly 10 or 15 ticks, and I don't get them where my mind wants them).  How to stick with, say, 10 ticks, but have 3 below 0.1?  I don't want/need them to line up with the first set of ticks, I just want maybe 5-7 between 0 and 0.1, and then 3-5 between 0.1 and 0.0001.

cbar_label = "Log base 10 of probability"
cbar_fontSize = 15
cbar_nBins = 25

cbar = plt.colorbar(mesh1, ax=axs.ravel().tolist())
cbar.ax.set_ylabel(cbar_label, fontsize = cbar_fontSize)
cbar.ax.locator_params(nbins=cbar_nBins)

cbar_tick_labels_pre = [float(t.get_text().replace('−','-')) for t in cbar.ax.get_yticklabels()]
cbar_round = 4
cbar_tick_labels = [round(10**t, cbar_round) for t in cbar_tick_labels_pre]

cbar_label_2 = "probability"

# define functions that relate the two colorbar scales
# e.g., Celcius to Fahrenheit and vice versa
def logP_to_P(x):
    val = 10**(np.ma.masked_invalid(x))
    return np.ma.masked_invalid(val)
def P_to_logP(x):
    val = np.log10(np.ma.masked_invalid(x))
    return np.ma.masked_invalid(val)

# create a second axes
cbar2 = cbar.ax.secondary_yaxis('left',functions=(logP_to_P,P_to_logP))
cbar2.set_ylabel(cbar_label_2, fontsize = cbar_fontSize, y=0.87)

#cbar_nBins_2 = 15
cbar_nBins_2 = 10

cbar2.locator_params(nbins=cbar_nBins_2)



Please include some data and integrate the code to make it reproducible. It will help you to receive valuable advice. In the current snippet mesh1 and axs are not defined.

Yes, sorry, very valid critique.  I will modify the question or do better next time.

You may want to use a different locator for the secondary axis (instead of the AutoLocator), e.g. a LogLocator:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,10))
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(Normalize(-5.8, -.2)), cax=ax)
cbar.ax.locator_params(nbins=25)

sec_ax = cbar.ax.secondary_yaxis('left', functions=(lambda x: 10**x, np.log10 ))
sec_ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(subs=(1, .6, .4, .2)))
sec_ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:g}')



Thank you!  This works, and I'm learning from investigating your code!
